# Xamarin Forms HtmlLoad nuGet don't work on ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm new in Xamarin, C# and VisualStudio
In my proyect Im trying display HTML content in a label using [Html Label](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin)

follow the steps in android work fine but in ios i have this error:

this is my finishedlaunching in appdelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        //Call HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize() before Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() in AppDelegate.cs
        HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

in the line of "global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() show me this error when launch;

**System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type Plugin.HtmlLabel.HtmlLabel, Plugin.HtmlLabel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute: (null)**

I try clean and rebuild, delete obj and bin folders and don't work, I think im missing some steps

Thanx for help

Comment: Did you install the plugin on both your PCL project as well as the platform project?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes I do, install in project  and in android/ios platform, as I said if I run with androind all work fine

Comment: Just use WebView

Comment: @YuriS No, I want do a listview with news import from joomla, a WebView is not a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

With the new versión (1.0.3) this problem is fixed!